# Get secondary IP of an NIC in Java

Tags: java, ip

The `eth1` interface of my VM is as follows:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:d3:c9:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.10.13/24 brd 10.0.10.255 scope global eth1
inet 10.0.10.101/24 scope global secondary eth1
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed3:c930/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I want to get the secondary IP (i.e. 10.0.10.101) of this interface in Java.

Using `getInetAddresses()` method of class `NetworkInterface`, I can get all IPs of this interface, but how can I know which one is the secondary IP?

Any help is appreciated.

=============================================================

Update: The following is a simplified version of my code. Basically, I want to figure out how the commented line (i.e. the `if` condition) should be written.

```
String getEth1SecondaryIp() throws SocketException {
    NetworkInterface eth1 = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth1");
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddrs = eth1.getInetAddresses();
    while(inetAddrs.hasMoreElements()) {
        InetAddress addr = inetAddrs.nextElement();
        //if(addr is secondary IP) {
            return addr.getHostAddress();
        //}
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code and log plz so that users interested in helping you out can do with ease.